# Python: subprocess.popen: read each line of output

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I'm having trouble reading my subprocess output by line. The subprocess simply greps the contents of a file against another file. The output, which should be a two column file, prints to stdout just fine. But when I try to read each line, it reads each char followed by \n:

```
#!/usr/bin/python    

import sys
import getopt
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

inputfile = ''
target = ''

try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"s:t:",['servers=', 'target='])
except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'getopt failure: exit'
        sys.exit()

for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-s", "--servers"):
                inputfile = arg
        if opt in ("-t", "--target"):
                boxwin = arg

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["grep -f " + inputfile + " " + target + " | awk '{print $2, $1}'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

output, error = p1.communicate()

print output # this prints normally

for line in output:
        print line # this prints each char of output followed by \n???
```

Expected output after reading by line:

```
abc 123
def 456
ghi 789
```

^^ this will print if I just "print output"

Actual output when using for loop to read each line:

```
a
b
c

1
2
3

d
e
f
```

...

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following :

```
for line in output.splitlines():
```

instead of:

```
for line in output:
```

Answer (score 10):

`for c in s:` reads one character at a time from a string `s` (as it should). To get a list of lines from a string instead, you could use [`.splitlines()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
lines = output.splitlines()
```

You don't need to call `.communicate()` to read the output line by line:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
    # do something with a line
```

You could modify the code to handle [buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279) differently or to enable [universal newlines support](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Cut about 5 lines of code out of my script.